# MS_Excel: How to add 2 period in the number list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can i create a number list that has two periods? example "1.4.1" in the below list. I would want the number format to remain.

[image]

For 1.4 I wrote the formula:

=MAX($A$1:C11)+0.1

Comment: That would be text and use concatenate() or &.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Solar Mike. I was hoping to get a formula/equation that could be dragged easily like the max equation with the format been numbers.

Comment: =concatenate(A1,B1,C1,"0.1") or =A1&B1&c1&"0.1" edit to suit.

Comment: You can't do this mathematically because there is no such number `1.4.1`.  If you want to use more than one decimal point then this has to be done as text and not as a number.  This can be done, but may involve a longer and more complicated formula than you're thinking.  There's some trickery that could be done if you have O365, so it will help to know your Excel version.

Comment: I have office 365.